# Accessing props in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to change a location in Google Maps API component upon a click on a title in my page file. Can't figure out how to access the component through a different file.

Tried different syntax, "MapContainer.func", MapContainer.props.func".

ContactPage.

```js
import GoogleMaps from '../../../components/GoogleMaps';
import MapContainer from '../../../components/GoogleMaps';

const breadcumbMenu = [
    { name: 'Home', route: '/' },
    { name: 'Contact', },
]

function bkLocation() {
    console.log('The bk link was clicked.');

    }

function mhLocation() {
    console.log('The mh link was clicked.');
    //MapContainer.changeLoc(40.712637, -74.008116); <-- need to use changeLoc right here
    }

function njLocation() {
    console.log('The nj link was clicked.');
    }


const ContactPage = () => {
    return (.......
```

GoogleMaps.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';
import './style.scss'


const style = {
    width: '70%',
    height: '100%',
    left: '14%'
  }



export class MapContainer extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    center: {lat:40.585384,
      lng:-73.951200  },
    zoom: 11
};

  state = {
    center: {
        lat: 40.7831,
        lng: -73.9712
    }
  }


  _changeLoc = (lt, ln) => {
    this.setState({
        center: {
            lat: lt,
            lng: ln
        }
    });};


  render() {
      return (
        <Map 
        google={this.props.google} 
        style={style} 
        zoom={14}
        initialCenter={{
          lat:40.585384,
          lng:-73.951200  
        }}
        center={this.props.center}
        >


          <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                  name={'Current location'} />

          <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>

          </InfoWindow>
        </Map>
      );
      }


}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ("AIzaSyBfumfF_4j5uvjaITGn_VO_pb3O59uu-oE")
})(MapContainer)
```

The error I am getting is that "changeLoc is not a function / undefined". I need the map api location change when the user clicks on a title (there are 3 titles with the console logs). Somehow I need to connect the changeLoc function and make it callable from the ContactPage file.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your case, it is better to use redux or mobx.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this the following way

Make _changeLoc static, then you will be able to call  MapContainer._changeLoc as you have defined

```
static _changeLoc = (lt, ln) => {
    this.setState({
        center: {
            lat: lt,
            lng: ln
        }
    });};
```

option 2 would be to use redux and add the refernece of your function into the redux store

Comment: TypeError: _components_GoogleMaps__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.default.changeLoc is not a function <-- thats what I am still receiving. Perhaps I am calling it wrong in the definition?

Comment: not changeLoc,its _changeLoc accordibng to your component

Comment: Still hits me with the same error, Matched the names in both components.

Comment: even after making _changeLoc static?

Comment: yes sir, still says it is not a function. I am new to react, or JS in general, still did not figure it out

Comment: I guess its because of the HOC that its not working.

Comment: What do you mean by HOC not working? any thing you can pinpoint with the hierarchy, or what should i look into?